# How can we integrate Power BI with Slack for getting the report downloaded directly into Slack?

Tags: powerbi, integration, powerbi-desktop, slack, microsoft-fabric

We need something like app for connecting Power BI to Slack.
So is there any app that could download the data from Power BI and Upload it into Slack channels.
Tried "Power BI Integration by Akvelon" but it is not getting installed. Trying some Automation triggers like Zapier,
But that too has integrated with Power BI.

Please let me know if there is way for approaching this problem ?

Slack has no app for connecting Power BI. It showed one app, but the app is not getting installed, Since Slack hasn't verified the app.

Any other ways for linking and getting the Power BI data through Slack